# 404 "This Method cannot be called this way" when getting user's inbox

Tags: support, api, inbox

I'm doing a POST request to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/<id>/inbox` to get the users' inbox items.
However I'm getting a 400 error on the request, and a JSON body saying it was a 404 error `"this method cannot be called this way"` and `"error_name: no method"`.

I've form encoded the parameters, and set the content-type to `form-urlencoded`.

Here's the request in fiddler:

[image: request]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that that route accepts `POST` requests (as it's non-actionable), so you should have better luck sending a `GET` request instead.

Routes that require auth tokens necessitate HTTPS, but still expect `GET` for read requests, and `POST` for writes.

Comment: Yep that was it.  For some reason I assumed it was a post.

Comment: @Tim When should we use POST? I can't see the documentation that says.

Comment: @Tim Whenever you're writing something, so creates/edits/et al